# Encryption with DES with urlENcode(encrypt)

Tags: encryption, des

I am attempting to use DES to encrypt / decrypt. However, the decrypt is not working. I keep getting the error: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of null

The decryption is from http://www.tero.co.uk/des/

I am using this to encode:

```
var decodedKey = decodeBase64(key);
var em = urlEncode(encrypt(decodedKey, value));
```

and then I am attempting to use this function to decrypt:

```
var emD = urlDecode(decrypt(decodedKey, em))
```

with

```
 function encrypt(key, message) {
        var ciphertext = des(key, message, 1, 0, null, 1);
        var encodedCiphertext = encodeBase64(ciphertext);
        return encodedCiphertext;

       }

       function decrypt(key,message) {
         var ciphertext = des(key, message, 0, 1, null,1);
         var plainText = decodeBase64(ciphertext);
         return plainText;
       };
```

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
urlEncode(encrypt(decodedKey, value));
```

you first encrypt then url-encode. When you need to decrypt, you need to first url-decode then decrypt - something like:

```
decrypt(decodedKey, urlDecode(em));
```

as opposed to decrypt then url-decode as you try with this statement:

```
urlDecode(decrypt(decodedKey, em));
```

Also, please note that **DES** is considered **insecure** and should be avoided. Use a secure cipher like **AES**.